# How to cleanly get all the programs' path that have visible windows opened?

Tags: directory, windows-10, window

Let's say that I open up Chrome. It should pop up one window, and on the taskbar, the application's icon will be underlined. I then minimize that window and open up Opera.

With the above scenario, the program should recognize that Chrome and Opera are the only two programs that have a window open (minimized or in focus) and return the application path of those programs. In other words, it should return:

[C:\"chrome install location"\chrome.exe , C:\"operainstall location"\opera.exe]

I haven't been able to find a clean and smart way to do this. Oftentimes random stuff like "Microsoft Text Input Application" and "NVIDIA GeForce Overlay" which have no visible window and are not shown in the taskbar gets returned.

Ideally, there is a solution in Python, but I know that it's not a low-level programming language. If you have an idea in Java or even C/C++, please share as well!